# Why does Array.prototype return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

It might be a stupid question, but why do I get an empty array when I console out `Array.prototype` ?

I was expecting the push and pop methods.

Comment: Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype);` to get them.

Comment: @some // that's useful! It worked!

Comment: It is one of the new methods in ECMAScript 262-5. It returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) on the object. Use `Object.keys(obj)` if you only want the enumerable properties. [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the built-in methods of prototypes are not enumerble, so they won't show up if you use `for..in` (which you shouldn't on arrays, but this is just an example). Since they not enumerable, they won't show up if you "console them out".

Comment: Or use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype);`

Answer (score 1):

"Note: Array.prototype does not refer to a single array, but to the Array() object itself."
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_array.asp

Comment: but then where do we get push and pop methods?

Comment: @Moon The properties are [still on the `prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype), but they aren't generally [`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description).

Comment: @Travis J // that's exactly what I mean. I thought the push and pop methods were defined in prototype. Aren't they?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski // ah! that makes sense.

Comment: Can we really trust w3schools?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - Is there evidence against it?